# Efficient way to count subsets with given sum

Tags: algorithm

Given N numbers I need to count subsets whose sum is S.

**Note : Numbers in array need not to be distinct.**

My current code is :

```
int countSubsets(vector<int> numbers,int sum)
{
    vector<int> DP(sum+1);
    DP[0]=1;
    int currentSum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
    {
        currentSum+=numbers[i];
        for (int j=min(sum,currentSum);j>=numbers[i];j--)
            DP[j]+=DP[j - numbers[i]];
    }
    return DP[sum];
}
```

Can their be any efficient way than this ?

Constraints are :

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 14
1 ≤ S ≤ 100000
1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10000
```

Also their are 100 test cases in a single file. So please help if their exist better solution than this one

Answer (score 1):

N is small (2^20 - is about 1 milion - 2^14 is really small value) - just iterate over all subsets, below I wrote pretty fast way to do that (bithacking). Treat integers as sets (that's enumerating subsets in Lexicographical order)

```
int length = array.Length;
int subsetCount = 0;
for (int i=0; i<(1<<length); ++i)
{
    int currentSet = i;
    int tempIndex = length-1;
    int currentSum = 0;

    while (currentSet > 0) // iterate over bits "from the right side"
    {
       if (currentSet & 1 == 1) // if current bit is "1"
          currentSum += array[tempIndex];

       currentSet >>= 1;
       tempIndex--;        
    }
    subsetCount += (currentSum == targetSum) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `==` has higher precedence than `&`, so `currentSet & 1 == 1` is parsed as `currentSet & (1 == 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that `N` is small: it is possible to generate all possible subsets of the given array and check if its sum is `S` for each of them. The time complexity is `O(N * 2 ** N)` or `O(2 ** N)`(it depends on the way of the generation). This solution should be fast enough for the given constraints.

Here is a pseudo code of an `O(2 ** N)` solution:

```
result = 0

void generate(int curPos, int curSum):
     if curPos == N:
         if curSum == S:
             result++
         return
     // Do not take the current element.
     generate(curPos + 1, curSum)
     // Take it.
     generate(curPos + 1, curSum + numbers[curPos])

generate(0, 0)
```

A faster solution based on the meet in the middle technique:

1. Let's generate all subsets for the first half of the array using the algorithm described above and put their sums into a map(which maps a sum to the number of subsets that have it. It can be either a hash table or just an array because `S` is relatively small). This step takes `O(2 ** (N / 2))` time.
2. Now let's generate all subsets for the second half and for each of them add the number of subset that sum up to `S - currentSum` e in the first half(using the map constructed in 1.), where the `currentSum` is the sum of all elements in the current subseta. Again, we have `O(2 ** (N / 2))` subsets and each of them is processed in `O(1)`.

The total time complexity is `O(2 ** (N / 2))`.

A pseudo code for this solution:

```
Map<int, int> count = new HashMap<int, int>() // or an array of size S + 1.
result = 0

void generate1(int[] numbers, int pos, int currentSum):
    if pos == numbers.length:
        count[currentSum]++
        return
    generate1(numbers, pos + 1, currentSum)
    generate1(numbers, pos + 1, currentSum + numbers[pos])

void generate2(int[] numbers, int pos, int currentSum):
    if pos == numbers.length:
        result += count[S - currentSum]
        return
    generate2(numbers, pos + 1, currentSum)
    generate2(numbers, pos + 1, currentSum + numbers[pos])

generate1(the first half of numbers, 0, 0)
generate2(the second half of numbers, 0, 0)
```

If `N` is odd, the middle element can go to either the first half or to the second one. It doesn't matter where it goes as long as it goes to exactly one of them.

Comment: Can you post most efficient according to you ?

Comment: Can we make it more fast by using memoisation or DP ?

Comment: @user3840069 It is possible to get something like `O(2 ** (N / 2))`, but is it necessary? Do you have any issues with this solutions' performance? It seems to me that it should work fast under given constraints.

Comment: No I have an issue. I want it more fast. Can you add that code ?

Comment: @user3840069 I have added a description of that algorithm.

Comment: for currentsum in second step we need to travel all the elements present in map if am not wrong ?

Comment: @user3840069 No, we only need to find the number of subsets with S - currentSum sum, which requires only one map look up.

Comment: @ kraskevich Please add code for it. I am getting confused between currentSum and set elements

Comment: @ kraskevich  Hey I tried your code but its giving runtime error . Here is code : http://ideone.com/3dYQCv

Comment: @user3840069 There are several bugs in your code. Here is a correct version: http://ideone.com/LQs2ZS.